# How to set column C value based on a initial column A,B,C value

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following table :

```
A     B       C
food  fruit   apple
food  fruit   
food  drink
food  fruit   
car   suv     ford
car   sedan   bmw
car   suv
car   sedan
```

Desired result :

```
 A     B       C
food  fruit   apple
food  fruit   apple
food  drink
food  fruit   apple 
car   suv     ford
car   sedan   bmw
car   suv     ford
car   sedan   bmw
```

How can complete column C based on the values in both Column A, B?  For example, if the value in Column A = food and Column B = fruit, then Column C should be filled with. Ideally, I want to do it without having to manually enter the column A, B pair and the corresponding column C value since my table has thousands of such combinations.

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two alternatives using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d1)[, C := C[C != ''], by = .(A,B)][]
setDT(d1)[, C := ifelse(all(C == ''), '', C[C != '']), by = .(A,B)][]
```

which both give:

> ```
> > d1
>       A     B     C
> 1: food fruit apple
> 2: food fruit apple
> 3: food drink      
> 4: food fruit apple
> 5:  car   suv  ford
> 6:  car sedan   bmw
> 7:  car   suv  ford
> 8:  car sedan   bmw
> ```

---

An alternative using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
d1 %>% 
  group_by(A, B) %>% 
  summarise(C = ifelse(all(C == ''), '', C[C != ''])) %>% 
  right_join(., d1, by = c('A','B')) %>% 
  select(A, B, C = C.x)
```

which gives a similar result.

Comment: I have been successfully using your suggestion : setDT(d1)[, C := C[C != ''], by = .(A,B)][]  Was wondering how I could apply this if I have an additional column to be filled, column D.  As an example, one row has the following values : A = food B=fruit C=apple D=red.  If another row has A=food, B=fruit, C= (blank), D= (blank), I want to fill columns in that row with C=apple, D=red.  Would appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: @user6340762 sorry, due to new year's eve celebration forgot to come back to this; a possible solution:```setDT(d1)[, `:=` (C = C[C != ''], D = D[D != '']), by = .(A,B)]```

Comment: Not a problem at all, certainly understandable!  And that seems to work.  Thank you!

Comment: Any suggestion on how/if I could ignore certain exceptions?  For example, most rows have the values A = food B=fruit C=apple D=red.  But a couple rows have the values A = food B=fruit C=banana D=yellow.  How can ignore the exceptions when filling additional blank rows so that if A=food and B=fruit, all blank C,D columns are always filled with C=apple and D= red (not C=banana, D=yellow).  Thank you!

Comment: @user6340762 You'll then need ```setDT(d1)[A == 'food' & B == 'fruit' (C == '' | D == ''), `:=` (C = 'apple', D = 'red')][]``` (or some variation on that)

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution using data.table.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dx)[,id:=1:.N] ## create variable to conserve origin order

dx[,C:={
  val <- unique(C[nzchar(C)])  
  if(length(val)==0) val <- ""    ## case empty C
  if(length(val)>1) val <- val[1] ## case multiple values

  rep(val,length(C))
  }, "A,B"][order(id)][,id:=NULL]

#       A     B     C
# 1: food fruit apple
# 2: food fruit apple
# 3: food drink      
# 4: food fruit apple
# 5:  car   suv  ford
# 6:  car sedan   bmw
# 7:  car   suv  ford
# 8:  car sedan   bmw
```

where :

```
dx <- read.table(text="A     B       C
food  fruit   apple
food  fruit   
food  drink
food  fruit   
car   suv     ford
car   sedan   bmw
car   suv
car   sedan",header=TRUE,fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `fill` from `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(C = ifelse(C == "", NA, C)) %>%
  group_by(A, B) %>%
  fill(C)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   A, B [4]
      A     B     C
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1   car sedan   bmw
2   car sedan   bmw
3   car   suv  ford
4   car   suv  ford
5  food drink  <NA>
6  food fruit apple
7  food fruit apple
8  food fruit apple
```

To get original row order:

```
df %>%
  mutate(C = ifelse(C == "", NA, C),
         ID = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(A, B) %>%
  fill(C) %>%
  arrange(ID) %>%
  select(-ID)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   A, B [4]
      A     B     C
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1  food fruit apple
2  food fruit apple
3  food drink  <NA>
4  food fruit apple
5   car   suv  ford
6   car sedan   bmw
7   car   suv  ford
8   car sedan   bmw
```

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(A = c("food", "food", "food", "food", "car", "car", 
"car", "car"), B = c("fruit", "fruit", "drink", "fruit", "suv", 
"sedan", "suv", "sedan"), C = c("apple", "", "", "", "ford", 
"bmw", "", "")), .Names = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```